# EXC_BAD_ACCESS with Code=2 While Objects Exist In Memory

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, memory-management, exc-bad-access

Can anybody kindly take his time and explain how it is possible to get such `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` exception while `parentVC` & `parentVC.audioHandler` & `parentVC.audioHandler.player` all do exist in memory ? ( they all are created with a `strong` pointer to them )

[image]

P.S: `player` is an `AVAudioPlayer` and obviously has an `isPlaying` method.

P.P.S: `player` is as same as `parentVC.audioHandler.player` and is defined a few lines higher as :

`AVAudioPlayer *player = parentVC.audioHandler.player;`

Comment: `player`(or something else) somehow end up with `0x1c` which is not valid pointer

Comment: player is defined a few lines above as : `AVAudioPlayer *player = parentVC.audioHandler.player;`

Comment: `player` is not a valid object.  Try running it the zombies instrument to see where it is disappearing.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem :

`player` is a valid `AVAudioPlayer` object and correctly exists in the memory.

The problem is that it is allocated with `init` method like :

`self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] init];`

Which is wrong because `AVAudioPlayer` doesn't have an `init` method, you should use `initWithURL` or `initWithData` instead !

Hope this can help somebody else.